# Can't import users.form when using django-users2

Tags: python, django, linux

Here is my import

```
from users.forms import RegistrationForm
```

If i just import like this, an exception will be raised:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

and I have tried using `django.setup()` after secure_key being set in settings

bur another exception will be raised:

> RuntimeError: Model class Article.models.Article_model doesn't declare
>   an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

But I have put Article in INSTALLED_APPS.
I don't know why

Here are where the exception was raised
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtDZK.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRAq9.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code. Copy and paste the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try upgrading to Django 1.11 - it allows you to use `get_user_model()` at runtime ([release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#django-contrib-auth)). Even if that doesn't fix the problem it's a good idea to upgrade - Django 1.10 will be unsupported when Django 2.0 is released soon.

Note that `django.setup()` is meant for stand-alone scripts. You shouldn't be using it in your settings.

Comment: Oh! when I upgrade to the newest version 2.0, there are some another problems. The Foreignkey field has a param call "on_delete", and it says I haven't given something to this param , but "on_delete" has default value --- None.   I finally re-upgrade to 1.11.7,and all problems disappeared.

Comment: As the error message suggests, you must specify [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) in Django 2.0, e.g. `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. Note that Django 2.0 has not been released yet, so it would be easier to stick with 1.11 which is an LTS.